# What can I add to a solution to water and ice to make it freeze normally?

Tags: ice

I'm trying to make ice cubes with salt in them, any tips on if this can be accomplished?

Comment: Make it cold enough and anything will freeze.

Comment: Pour liquid nitrogen on that bad boy. Or are there other restrictions you're not telling us, such as using a conventional home freezer?

Answer (score 2):

The phase diagram for salt and water looks like ([image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brine)):

[image]

You'll presumably be starting from a  relatively low salt concentration, say 5%, and I've maked this with a red dot. As you cool your system it will precipitate pure ice, containing no salt, and as a result the remaining liquid will get saltier. Your system will move down the phase boundary line, in the direction shown by the arrow and the magenta dots, until the salt concentration reaches 23.3% (the blue dot), at which point everything will freeze. This happens about -22°C.

Unless you have a super cold freezer you're unlikely to reach such low temperatures. So what you will end up with is cubes of pure ice with liquid inclusions of very salty water.